Can I quote from a youtube interview in a book I am writing?
The interview of Dr. Lloyd Rudy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JL1oDuvQR08
Can I transcribe what Dr Rudy says and quote him in a book I am writing?

Without commenting on the legal question, you know they have text, you do not need to transcribe it,

europe
Yes, quotations are usually ok, regardless of the source or it's copyright status. The quotation should be as short as possible and reasonable, though. If you need to use a larger statement, it would be better to rewrite it in your own words, and use a literal quote only for the parts where it's relevant that the wording is exactly as in the interview (e.g. because of a very destinctive expression).
Quotation does require that you provide the proper source of the quote together with it. How much text a "short" quote is, is not so clear and appears to be contested, though.

This would be a very good answer if the question were about plagiarism. It is not quite as correct in terms of copyright analysis.

@bdb484 I guess I should add something like [tag:europe]. A quotation according to European copyright is not the same as fair use in the US.
